# Add an object from another class to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, class, jpanel, draw

Ok i have a JPanel such as this one :

```
public class GUI {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Net");

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
public GUI()
{
frame.setSize(835,650);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);          
frame.add(panel);
panel.setSize(600,600);
panel.setLocation(215,5);}
```

There are some other panels in there tables etc. My main is this one :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ 
    @Override
    public void run(){
    //new GUI();
    new GUI().buildTable();

     }

   });
```

And there i another class this one :

```
public class DrawPlanes extends GUI 
{    

private static int centreX, centreY, radius;
private Color colour;

public DrawPlanes()
{
centreX = 300;
centreY = 300;
radius = 200;
colour = Color.BLACK;
}

public DrawPlanes(int centreX,int centreY, int radius, Color colour)
{
this.centreX = centreX;
this.centreY = centreY;
this.radius = radius;
this.colour = colour;

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

  super.paintComponent(g);
  System.out.println("ppp");
  Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;           
  g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2F));  
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.drawOval(centreX - radius , centreY - radius, radius * 2 , radius * 2);
  ......
    }
   }
```

Now i cant add this class to my panel i tried creating an object in main and then adding the object to my panel. I ve also tried

```
panel.add(new DrawPlanes(int x, int y, int radius,Color colour));
```

but it didnt get the drawing added in the panel.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `DrawPanel` is not a component, it extends `GUI` which is not a component either.
- `container.add(component)` function expects a Component, in Swing essentially `JComponent` and it's extending component: `JPanel, JLabel, JButton` etc.
- extends `DrawPanel` to a `JComponent` or `JPanel`. However they both are basically some other than the fact that `JComponent` is non-opaque while `JPanel` is opaque.

Comment: well then just there isn't a way to add the drawing of DrawPlanes class in my panel?!!?

Comment: please, Read the answer more carefully. I have specifically said to extend `DrawPanel` to `JPanel` or `JComponent`

Comment: Ok i ve extended DrawPlanes to JPanel i added it in the JPanel panel.add(new DrawPlanes(300,300,200,Color.BLACK)); i ve setted the Background Colour of the panel red to see whats going on and it now appears the whole panel red and just a small square grey where i believe it contains my drawing.I ve also tried to change opaque in order to prevent some incompatibility but nothing changed

Comment: @Renobatio, you should understand that your comment arises just another question. Please post another question as the post will not fit with the quested you have posted